# Trying to create a list of Transforms of objects that enter a sphere in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to both align my object with the surrounding objects and have the object try and get the average position of it's surrounding objects,I am trying to do this by creating a list of all the objects that enter a sphere and using there transform to do the calculations however unity only accepts lists of colliders. I would really appreciate some help or advice, further info is that this script is on 200 clones of the same gameobject and the script below gives the error
Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Collider[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

```
IEnumerator Flock()
{

    Collider[] NearbyBoids = Physics.OverlapSphere(BoidVec, VisionRange, BoidMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Collide);

    foreach (Collider Boid in NearbyBoids)
    {
        List<Transform> context = NearbyBoids;
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: OK so your list only exsits in that for loop so if there were 100, 100 times you set a new variable to be the whole list... but it doesnt go anywhere...

Comment: My plan was to somehow go through each element in the list and convert it to the Transform data type. I know it doesn't do anything but that it because it isn't in a usable data type yet as soon as I can convert it it will go somewhere.

Comment: Why is this a coroutine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to go about this.

Quick way is to use LINQ. To do this you need the using namespace declaration

```
using System.Linq;

Collider[] arrayOfNearbyTransforms = Physics.OverlapSphere(BoidVec, VisionRange, BoidMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Collide);
List<Transform> listOfAllNearbyTransforms = arrayOfNearbyTransforms.Select(x => x.transform).ToList();
```

The issue with the code you've posted is that you're creating a list within your loop. Variables declared within a loop only exist within that loop's execution, so you're essentially creating as many lists as there are colliders, while using none of them.

Instead, you should create the list outside your loop, and add transform components from within the loop

```
    void Flock()
    {
        // This is the array of colliders you've gathered from nearby objects
        Collider[] NearbyBoids = Physics.OverlapSphere(BoidVec, VisionRange, BoidMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Collide);

        // This is a brand new list. It's empty at the moment
        List<Transform> listOfAllNearbyTransforms = new List<Transform>();

        // We're looping through every collider in the array.
        foreach (Collider currentColliderReference in NearbyBoids)
        {
            // Everything that happens in here happens once for every collider.
            // The variable currentColliderReference refers to the collider we're looking at during this part of the loop. So throughout the loops execution, it will change to refer to every collider in your array, one at a time.

            // We get a reference to the current collider's transform component
            Transform transformOfCurrentCollider = currentColliderReference.transform;

            // We add that to the list of transform component
            listOfAllNearbyTransforms.Add(transformOfCurrentCollider);
        }

        // At this point listOfAllNearbyTransforms will be a list of all transforms within the area specified in your OverlapSphere() call
    }
```

As you can tell, I've also changed the return type to void. There's no reason for this function to be a coroutine

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I sill need to solve the issue of turning the list of Colliders into Transforms, in your second exemplar code you had a list called "listOfAllNearbyTransforms " but my issue is that that list doesn't exist and the closest thing I have is the "Collider[] NearbyBoids" system but that stores colliders and not transforms

Comment: The second code snippet does turn your array of colliders into a list of the transforms of the colliders. I'll change my reply to make it more apparent what's happening

Comment: I didn't down vote I don't have the reputation to vote yet this was my first post, thanks for the help though it's really appreciated. I fixed the problem by creating a script that instantiates each game object, it then adds the gameobject to an array which I can easily get transforms from essentially doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the number of iterations your Boids have to make, it might make sense to just have them keep a context list of other Boids that enter or leave a trigger volume you set up in the inspector as an "area of sight". Then you can have each Boid evaluate it's own up to date context in `Update`.

Something along the lines of:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Boid : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<Transform> context = new List<Transform>();

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // good if you want to call the other Boid component
        Boid boid = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Boid>();

        if (boid != null)
        {
            context.Add(other.transform);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        // Pretty efficient, requires tagging of boid objects
        if (other.CompareTag("boidTag"))
        {
            context.Remove(other.transform);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        foreach(Transform otherBoid in context)
        {
            // doing some stuff here based on boids within context
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I wouldnt do this as a CoRoutine at this stage, Ive kept your code as similar as possible.  Unless you really imagine a lot of units 1000's the longest part of the code to run is the overlapsphwere.

```
List<Transform> context = new List<Transform>();

    IEnumerator Flock()
    {
        context.Clear(); // if there are 1000s this could be costly
        Collider[] NearbyBoids = Physics.OverlapSphere(BoidVec, VisionRange, BoidMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Collide);

        foreach (Collider Boid in NearbyBoids)
        {
            context.Add(NearbyBoids.transform);
        }
        yield return null;
    }
```

this gives you a class level list of context, which you can access from elsewhere.

Then your context list will have current transforms, but I wouldnt want to run this too often, personally Id use a list and triggers...  So, add to list onenter, and remove from list onleave..